# How to traverse JSON object locating particular property and pushing its contents to array?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

I am working with a JSON object which can have a property `ids` at any leaf. I want to traverse the object and find all of the instances of the `ids` property and store each id in a collection.

Mocked up JSON Object (the `ids` property could be at much deeper property locations).

```js
{
  "id": "b38a683d-3fb6-408f-9ef6-f4b853ed1193",
  "foo": {
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881"
      },
      {
        "id": "d1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999"
      },
      {
        "id": "b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71"
      }
    ],
    "baz": "super"
  },
  "bar": {
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881"
      },
      {
        "id": "d1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999"
      },
      {
        "id": "b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using the following code to traverse the above JSON.

```js
var jsonFile = require('./file_test.json'); // the above in my local directory

function traverse(obj, ids) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && obj[prop]) {
      if (prop == 'ids') {
        for (var i = obj[prop].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          ids.push(obj[prop][i]._id);
        };
      }
      traverse(obj[prop], ids);
    }
  }
}

var ids = new Array();
traverse(jsonFile, ids);

console.log('ids', ids);
```

The above nets the following:

```js
ids
[
  'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71',
  'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999',
  'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881',
  'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71',
  'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999',
  'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881'
]
```

While my code works I am not convinced that I am doing this the most efficient or best way. Is there a better way to find all instances of the `ids` property? Perhaps without passing in an array but returning one? Or setting up for a callback with an `ids` array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data was actually a JSON string, and not a JavaScript object, you could have something like:

```
// assuming `json` is the data string
var ids = [];
var data = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
    if (key === "id") 
        ids.push(value);

    return value;
});
```

See `reviver` on [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

Comment: Does not answer the question correctly. The author is looking for the ids in the `ids` properties, not the top level id. In particular `b38a683d-3fb6-408f-9ef6-f4b853ed1193` gets returned, but shouldn't be.

Answer (score 3):

what you have is fine, but this is a little shorter and uses the .map function:

```
var jsonFile = require('./file_test.json'); // the above in my local directory
function traverse(obj) {
    var ids = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && obj[prop]) {
            if (prop == 'ids') {
                ids = obj[prop].map(function(elem){
                   return elem.id;
               })
            }
            ids =ids.concat(traverse(obj[prop]));
        }
    }
    return ids;
}

var ids =traverse(jsonFile);

console.log('ids', ids);
```

Comment: It sounded to me like ids could be nested on ids, so I left traverse following the if.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically trying to do is a tree search of this JSON object, am I right? So if we assume that `ids` is always a leaf then we do not need to `traverse` those nodes as we know they are at the leaf and will contain what we want.

- Change the `if {...} traverse` **to** `if {...} else {traverse}`

If it is possible to change the data structure of `ids` to a list of strings instead of a list of objects then you will be able to save the iteration over the array and just merge it onto the `ids` array passed in, but it depends completely on the context and whether or not you can make this change!

Sorry I'm not of more help!

Comment: Yes basically a tree search of the JSON object. Unfortunately, can't change ids to a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ES5 is available natively or via a [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim):

```
function gimmeIds(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj||{})
        .reduce(function(ids, key) {
            if(key === 'ids') {
                return ids.concat(obj[key].map(function(idObj) {
                    return idObj.id;
                }));
            }

            if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
                return ids.concat(gimmeIds(obj[key]));
            }

            return ids;
        }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) this becomes very simple. Note that you can easily specify what is targeted (in this case `**.ids[*].id`)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { id: 'b38a683d-3fb6-408f-9ef6-f4b853ed1193', foo: { ids: [{ id: 'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881' }, { id: 'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999' }, { id: 'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71' }], baz: 'super' }, bar: { ids: [{ id: 'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881' }, { id: 'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999' }, { id: 'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71' }] } };

const findIds = (input) => objectScan(['**.ids[*].id'], { rtn: 'value' })(input);

console.log(findIds(data));
/* => [ 'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71',
  'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999',
  'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881',
  'b68d0c8c-548e-472f-9b01-f25d4b199a71',
  'd1cc529d-d5d2-4460-b2bb-acf24a7c5999',
  'bd0bf3bd-d6b9-4706-bfcb-9c867e47b881' ]
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)