# How to traverse each property of JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON that is coming from database

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
      "batter": [
        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
      ]
    },
    "topping": [
      { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
      { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
      { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
      { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
      { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
      { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
      { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
      "batter": [
        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
      ]
    },
    "topping": [
      { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
      { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
      { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
      { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
      { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to traverse all the properties of above JSON with below jquery ajax call method

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myPage.aspx/CallingFunction',
  type: 'POST',
  data: '{}',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.d) // showing json is fine
    var MyData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    for (i = 0; i < MyData.length; i++) {
      //How to travers all the properties defined in JSON
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Very similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993038/how-to-traverse-json-object-locating-particular-property-and-pushing-its-content

Comment: You can use nested loops or recursion to solve walk through the data structure, but what exactly do you need to do with the data?

Answer (score 0):

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) could give you what you want:

```
var i, key, value;
var keys = Object.keys(MyData);
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  key = keys[i];
  value = MyData[key];
  // ...
}
```